# Why notepad takes taking longer than LTViewr

Tags: text, notepad

Why Notepad takes 25 seconds to open a 6MB text file
While Large Text File Viewer takes 10 seconds to open 600MB text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, Notepad is loading (or is attempting) to load the entire file into RAM memory, whereas LTFV is simply caching a certain portion of the file, but not the full content.  You will also notice that for very large files (say 100MB or more), Notepad will tend to have a herky jerky performance as you scroll through it, while tools such as LTFV or Notepad++ will have smooth performance even for very large files.

Comment: in LTV you can see all data, and scroll it all. also you can search it which mean it is all in the memory

Comment: @asmgx But that doesn't necessarily mean that the whole file is loaded into RAM at the same time.